# Genesis 1:3; 1:5 and 1:16

Tags: genesis, old-testament, creation

This is a simple question but it's making me confused.

- In Genesis 1:3 God created light.
- In Genesis 1:5 "And the evening and the morning were the first day."
- In 1:16 "Genesis 1:16: And God made two great lights; the greater light to rule the day, and the lesser light to rule the night: [he made] the stars also."

  What I'm confused about is that, in 1:5 evenings were already happening. But only in 1:16 He created the Sun and the Moon. Was God regulating by Himself the light on Earth, then left us with the Sun and the Moon?

Can someone explain?, sorry if the question it's silly.

God bless us all :-)

Comment: This link from curiousdannii has many great answers.

Answer (score 2):

This question is about confusion in reading the creation account in Genesis 1:1-2:4a, and the confusion arises because you are trying to see the creation story as a literal account. The existence of daylight and evening before the creation of the sun and moon is only the most superficial issue in understanding the creation story. Contrary to science, a literal reading would also mean that the earth was a cold and lonely rock floating through the emptiness of space until the sun, moon and stars were created on day three. Yet there was liquid water at the beginning of creation, and plants grew before the sun was there to warm them.

Faced by the apparent contradictions in Genesis, it is more reasonable to see the creation account as allegorical, just as many early Church Fathers did. For example, Origen (*[De Principiis](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/origen125.html)*, Book 4.1.16):

> ... as even these do not contain throughout a pure history of events, which are interwoven indeed according to the letter, but which did not actually occur. Nor even do the law and the commandments wholly convey what is agreeable to reason. For who that has understanding will suppose that the first, and second, and third day, and the evening and the morning, existed without a sun, and moon, and stars? and that the first day was, as it were, also without a sky? And who is so foolish as to suppose that God, after the manner of a husbandman, planted a paradise in Eden, towards the east, and placed in it a tree of life, visible and palpable, so that one tasting of the fruit by the bodily teeth obtained life? and again, that one was a partaker of good and evil by masticating what was taken from the tree? And if God is said to walk in the paradise in the evening, and Adam to hide himself under a tree, I do not suppose that any one doubts that these things figuratively indicate certain mysteries, the history having taken place in appearance, and not literally...

Comment: "Contrary to science, a literal reading would also mean that the earth was a cold and lonely rock floating through the emptiness of space until the sun, moon and stars were created on day three." This is incorrect. If there was a source of light (from whatever source), then there would necessarily be heat as well.

Comment: @bruisedreed Although the Bible does not seem to say so, I guess we could speculate on a source of warmth as well, one which disappeared just as the sun was created to replace it, but still a lonely rock with no sun to orbit. By "contrary to science" I meant that according to science, there should be no doubt that the sun and stars are older than the earth.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time answering so please excuse my brevity.  To me the answer is very simple...  God is light.  There are many times in the scriptures that I remember reading this.  If God is light then it makes perfect sense to me that He is the light that gave life on Day 3.

Comment: Is not the usage of light in such contexts is *figurative*? In my Protestant/EVFC background I've never heard that literal interpretation, although I've heard many other literal stories - including that of a very literal creationism. Or is God really part of the Electromagnetic Spectrum? I don't know :) That is, supporting biblical/cannon/church references should probably be supplied to support this answer.